# How to redirect to another page after submitting a form

Tags: laravel, redirect

How to redirect to another page after submitting a form with my controller. the form is working fine but when i use the code like this i get a blank page and if i use

```
return view('leave.signUp');
```

it works but still remains in the page of the form and i want it to be redirected to another page.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $employee = new Employee;
        $employee->lname = $request->input('lname');
        $employee->fname = $request->input('fname');
        $employee->oname = $request->input('oname');
        $employee->employee_id = $request->input('staffId');
        $employee->college = $request->input('college');
        //$employee->salary_level = $request->input('salaryGradeLevel');
        $employee->employee_type = $request->input('staffType');
        $employee->employee_category= $request->input('staffCategory');
        $employee->date_of_first_appointment= $request->input('dateOfFirstAppointment');
        $employee->date_of_last_appointment= $request->input('dateOfLastAppointment');

        $employee->country = $request->input('country');
        $employee->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $employee->title = $request->input('title');
        $employee->marital_status = $request->input('maritalStatus');
        $employee->email = $request->input('email');
        $employee->phone_number = $request->input('phoneNumber');
        $employee->date_of_birth = $request->input('dateOfBirth');
        $employee->place_of_birth = $request->input('placeOfBirth');
        $employee->religion = $request->input('religion');
        $employee->origin = $request->input('stateOfOrigin');
        $employee->local_government_area = $request->input('localGovernmentArea');
        $employee->address = $request->input('address');
        $employee->permanent_address = $request->input('permanentAddress');
        $employee->extra_curicullar_activities = $request->input('extraCuricularActivities');
        $employee->save();

        $nextOfKin = new NextOfKin;
        $nextOfKin->employee_id = $employee->employee_id;
        $nextOfKin->title = $request->input('Ntitle');
        $nextOfKin->surname = $request->input('Nsurname');
        $nextOfKin->firstname = $request->input('Nfirstname');
        $nextOfKin->othername = $request->input('Nothername');
        $nextOfKin->relationship = $request->input('Nrelationship');
        $nextOfKin->email = $request->input('Nemail');
        $nextOfKin->phone_number = $request->input('NphoneNumber');
        $nextOfKin->contact_address = $request->input('Naddress');
        $nextOfKin->save();

        return redirect(route('application'));
    }


}
```

this is my web.php

```
Route::match(['post','get'],'application', 'LeavessController@index');
Route::match(['post','get'],'signUp', 'signUpsController@index');
Route::get('approved', 'LeavesController@getLeaveApproved');
Route::match(['post','get'], 'leaveType', 'LeavesController@getleaveType');
Route::match(['post','get'], 'leaveDepartment', 'LeavesController@getleaveDepartment');
Route::get('allLeave', 'LeavesController@getallLeave');
Route::get('leaveViewDetails', 'LeavesController@getleaveViewDetails');
Route::get('/get-leave-days/{leaveType}', 'LeavesController@getLeaveDays');
```

Comment: If you get a "blank" page it's always a good idea to check your Laravel log to see what caused the error. I guess it's the wrong usage of that `route()` part

Comment: @kerbholz Please how would you advise i use the route();

Answer (score 2):

```
return redirect()->route('application');
```

The param for `route()` is what you defined in your routes with `name(...)`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes

Besides that, I recommend you to read the laravel docs about Controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

The `index` is only for returning the database entries. For inserting data into the database use `store` .

Comment: Please hw do i create a name route, have been trying as you said but am not getting it. Am actually new to laravel. Please

Comment: E. g. change in your `routes/web.php` this line `Route::match(['post','get'],'application', 'LeavessController@index');` to `Route::match(['post','get'],'application', 'LeavessController@index')->name('application');` . For more information check this out:  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a "simple" URL use:

```
return redirect('home/dashboard');
```

(replace 'home/dashboard' with the actual URL you want to redirect to)

---

To redirect to a named route use:

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

(where `login` is the name of your route)

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirects

Comment: with  return redirect('application'); the code skipped all my form to store data and went directly to the url. i want it to excequte the code in the controller before redirecting. thank you

Comment: Route [application] not defined. when i used return redirect()->route('login');

Comment: Do you have a route _named_  `application` in your `web.php`? A route with `->name('application')`? Looks like you don't. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes